# Hadoop HBase scripts on Linux Mint gives strange errors

Tags: shell, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, linux-mint

I have installed Hadoop and Pig on my Mint (Ubuntu-like) virtual machine. I keep getting strange error messages when running scripts. In fact, when I run hadoop commands I also get errors but at least it works, but with HBase it just fails.

For example, running `sh hadoop -rmr /home/myoutput` I get:

```
hadoop: 102: [: fs: unexpected operator
Deleted hdfs://localhost/home/myoutput
```

When I run `start-hbase` it starts fine.

When I run `sh hbase shell` I get:

```
hbase: 163: hbase: [[: not found

hbase: 163: hbase: [[: not found

hbase: 197: hbase: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

These lines in the hbase script are:

163: if [[ $f = *sources.jar ]]

197: function append_path() {
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Mint is not just ubuntu-like, it is actually built on ubuntu, so you should be able to find the answer pretty easy for that.
Also, my suggestion to you is to tag this question with ubuntu, not mint.

Comment: I fixed it myself! I change the script so instead of: "function append_path() {" It's just: "append_path() {" and it works!